# Java: do file menu clicks take focus?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable

I had a problem with tables whereby a cell being edited did not store its new value until the user pressed enter or tab, whereas I wanted it to commit the value as soon as focus was lost as I was finding that selecting 'file -> save' whilst editing a cell caused that cell's data to be lost.
I found that you can simply set

`table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);`

which works well for every change of focus except when the file menu is selected, in which case the cell stays in edit mode.
My question is, does setting this property not behave as one might expect it to, or does focus work differently for menu items by default in Java?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make the menu items focusable then you will need to add code like the following in your Save Action:

```
if (table.isEditing())
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

Comment: I tried that before and got some unexpected behaviour, but I gave it another shot a different way which seems to work now.  It would be annoying if I couldn't guarantee that my table will only be dealing with Strings, but fortunately it will.  I'll post the code below.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the JMenuItem source code there is a function call being made to `initFocusability()` witch in turns calls `setFocusable(false)`.

Java Doc for initFocusability()

> Inititalizes the focusability of the the `JMenuItem`.
>   `JMenuItem`'s are focusable, but subclasses may want to be,
>   this provides them the and invoke something else, or nothing at all.
>   Refer to {@link javax.swing.JMenu#initFocusability} for the motivation
>   of this.

Java Doc from [JMenu.JMenu#initFocusability](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d5/teaching/ss05/is05/javadoc/javax/swing/JMenu.html#initFocusability%28%29)

> Overriden to do nothing. We want JMenu to be focusable, but JMenuItem
>   doesn't want to be, thus we override this do nothing. We don't invoke
>   setFocusable(true) after super's constructor has completed as this has
>   the side effect that JMenu will be considered traversable via the
>   keyboard, which we don't want. Making a Component traversable by the
>   keyboard after invoking setFocusable(true) is OK, as setFocusable is
>   new API and is speced as such, but internally we don't want to use it
>   like this else we change the keyboard traversability.

So it sounds like you need to call `setFocusable(true);`.

Comment: Hm, this sounded just right, but I tried it and it doesn't seem to help.  I also tried calling isFocasable on my menu before calling setFocasable, and it seems it was already true anyway.

Comment: don't burn the bed because you feel cold in your living room :-) Or in other words: typically, ui flow relies on of menu/items being only _temporary_ focusOwners. Don't confuse that for the sake of an unsolved problem!

Answer (score -1):

I have found that a combination of the two answers above has solved this problem.  I have a focusable menu bar, and have added a `DefaultCellEditor` with an overridden `getTableCellEditorComponent` method that adds a focus listener to  stop editing:

```
table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()){
@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
             boolean isSelected,
             int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    c.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
    {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
        {
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
        {
            stopCellEditing();
        }
    });
    return c;
    }
});
```

Comment: not safe enough - the editing component might not even _have_ the focus on editing. Plus even if it has, the listener will fail to fire if the component is a compound component (like f.i. a comboBox) Generally, relying on focus events isn't a good idea when you want to guard against edited data loss: the actual focus transfers surrounding editing tend to be pretty undefined.

Comment: -1 expanding on Kleopatra's comments the editor only gets focus if you double click on the cell or use F2 to invoke the editor. There is nothing to stop the user from simply typing text when the cell has focus. In this case the text is appended to the editor, without the editor getting focus so your code will NOT be executed. Also, this code will add a new FocusListener to the editor component every time the editor is invoked.

Comment: I take your point about making multiple editors - that's bad.  I've now changed my code so that I have my own editor that extends the DefaultCellEditor and adds a listener once on construction.
As for the other problems, they pretty much make that fix redundant I suppose...I have tried editing the cell by just typing rather than officially invoking the editor and it still seems to work fine, although I understand that that's hardly conclusive and can't represent every case on every platform.  Are you able to suggest a more reliable way I could go about this?